# How to solve this issue by adding visitors into an array from textfields in cells of the tableview?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3, swift4

Here I have a view in which the user can enter his name, mobile number, visitor age, visitor name and visitor gender in a view that appears on top WHICH IS A CELL...(TopCell).

And below that cell there is another cell which contains another Cell (ButtonCell) which contains 2 buttons named Add Visitor and  Submit.

There is another cell named AdditionalCell - which I will tell you what is it used for.

Here what I need is...If the user needs to add more than 1 visitor, the user needs to click on "Add Visitor" Button and the  AdditionalCell containing 3 fields named Visitor Name, Age and Gender should appear below.

And each time when the user clicks on add visitor, the last cell's datas should be added into the visitors array.

And when the visitor decides if its enough, the last cell's data should be added to the array when The submit button is also pressed.

This is how my current code looks like

[My current code Github link](https://github.com/jaseelop/VisitorsRegistration)

[image]!

[image: When user press Add Visitor]

Comment: Readers want to help here, but we need the code in the question itself. A link to a repo is liable to be deleted, or fixed/changed, and that would change the nature of the question. Could you edit the question with the relevant piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a temporary array for the additional visitors? Then stepping through them when the button is pressed adding a cell for each? Then once the user submits, a for loop would through the temp array adding them to the visitor array with the rest and then clearing the temp.

Comment: Nope...i dont know how to...can u please write it in the code...i have ahared the github link...thank u for the answer btw